# BSOD Internal power error in start up

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, bsod

I have a netbook with windows 7 started.
Nothing Special Atom 1.6ghz 1Gb ram etc

When I'm trying to turn if on It throws BSOD with internal Power Error ( sorry but I can't say exact code because laptop resets immediately after bsod).

I tried using `repair tool` and turn to factory state but it freezes.
Same effect with producers tool to turn to factory state.

I dismounted HDD and plugged it to my PC and this is what I got:

- same error windows not booting
- after connecting laptop Hdd like a slave System see that disk. See system partision
- Partition name is visible
- System can not open this partition nor show size of it so I can't get dump from it.

What can I do beside sending laptop to the service?
Bsod:
[image]
Ignore processor count because this is showing my working pc. Onbroken there is only Atom 1 core with HT

Comment: Doesn't sound like much you can do. Have you ran diagnostics from the manufacturer? Will it boot to a Live CD or Windows 7 CD?

Comment: Any diagnostic tool from manufacturer which exists in the hidden partion freezes. Laptop doesn't have disk drive. It's look like that system partition is faulty because data partition can be accessed

Comment: upload the folder **C:\Windows\Minidump**

Comment: Updated my question with dump.